# How to implement nested resources using jsonapi-resorces gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonapi-resources

I have a Posts resource, and a User Rating resource.

In my `routes.rb`, I have nested the user rating within the posts:

```
jsonapi_resources :posts do
  jsonapi_resources :user_ratings
end
```

This has exposed the endpoint `/posts/{id}/user-ratings` correctly.

However when testing this end point with an `{id}`, it is returning all `user-ratings`, not just the `user-ratings` associated to that post id.

In my posts resource, I have tried adding: `has_many :user_ratings`, in user ratings I have tried adding: `has_one :post`.

In my models, I have added `has_many` and `belongs_to`.

Yet nothing I have tried is making the api return just the user ratings associated with a particular post id.

Any insight would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special construction for related resources, in routes.rb:

```
jsonapi_resources :posts do
  jsonapi_related_resources :user_ratings
end
```

Post resource should have

```
has_many :user_ratings
```

It will add route /posts/{id}/user_ratings and ratings will be fetched through post resource, you can also override records_for_* method there to get more control:

```
def records_for_user_ratings
   super.published
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `UserRating` model try a `has_one :issue`

In routes.rb, you don't need to nest `user_ratings` in `posts`

When you run `rake routes`you should see nesting `posts\:post_id\user_ratings` even though in routes.rb its not specified as nested

Answer (score -4):

Make sure the index action of the controller uses that `post_id` parameter to filter `user_ratings`. For example:

```
    # GET /user_ratings
    def index
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @user_ratings = @post.user_ratings

      render json: @user_ratings
    end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note: OP is using the jsonapi-resources gem, which takes the place of tradition rails controllers.